# error: resource android:color not found

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Estoy creando un splash en Flutter y obtengo el siguiente error:

> error: resource android:color/primary not found.

Mi archivo bg_Color.xml se encuentra dentro de la carpeta drawable

bg_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:drawable="@android:color/primary" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <!-- <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
    </item> -->
</shape>
```

mi archivo color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name = "green">#808080</color>
</resources>
```

A que se debe este error ?

Comment: En drawable="@android:color/primary" por que usas primary? si tu color se llama `green`?   usa: drawable="@color/green"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error indica que hay un color el cual no existe y al cual tratas de hacer referencia.

Puedes definir el color que deseas dentro de el archivo `color.xml`, por ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
   <color name="primary">#00FF00</color>
   <color name = "green">#808080</color>
</resources>
```

y usarlo de esta forma en tu archivo `bg_color.xml`:

```
 <solid android:drawable="@color/primary" />
```

de otra forma si el color que deseas usar es "green", definido en `color.xml` usalo de esta forma:

```
 <solid android:drawable="@color/green" />
```